# Laravel nova submenu item

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I have menu

[menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mt2yb.jpg)

I want to add submenu for DOCS (below All docs).
And it not resource, just link.
How I can do it?

Comment: if it's not a resource, you will have to overwrite the blade component nova uses to display the sidebar

Comment: post code not images

Comment: How I can do it?

Answer (score 1):

For adding a link to the **left** Laravel Nova menu

1. Open `App/Providers/NovaServiceProvider`
2. In `boot` method add this code

   ```
   Nova::mainMenu(function (Request $request) {
       return [
           MenuItem::externalLink('Docs', 'https://example.com'),
       ];
   });
   ```

[image: Link in the left Laravel Nova menu]

For adding a link to the **top right** Laravel Nova menu

1. Open `App/Providers/NovaServiceProvider`
2. In `boot` method add this code

   ```
   Nova::userMenu(function (Request $request, Menu $menu) {
       $menu->prepend(
           MenuItem::externalLink('Docs', 'https://example.com'),
       );

       return $menu;
   });
   ```

[image: Link in the top right Laravel Nova menu]